# I'm trying to make my program throw an IllegalArgumentException if the input is not a number

Tags: java

*I'm trying to make it to were is will throw my exception if the input is not a number and i cant figure it out, Could someone help me get on the right track*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class calculations
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number;
            int total = 0;
            try
            {

            } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                //error
            }
            while (true)
            {
                number = scan.nextInt();

                if (number == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                total += number;
            }
            System.out.println("Total is " + total);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're catching `IllegalArgumentException ` instead of throwing it

Comment: Define "number".

Comment: Why do you think that a `try`...`catch` block would do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throw exception in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706553/throw-exception-in-java)

Comment: Integer numbers, or any numbers, i.e. floats?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [hasNextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt), which will allow you to check if the next token in the stream can be parsed as an int.

```
if (! scanner.hasNextInt()) throw new IllegalArgumentException()
```

Comment: I haven't programmed in Java in a while, but would that work if the next item were a "." (period) ?

Comment: Yes it should, it is checking if there is an int or not. A '.' is not an int, so hopefully there won't be a problem.